# How to simultaneously control 8 motor drives with a single digital output pin...or also control just 1 drive with same pin?

Tags: microcontroller, stepper-motor

I am working on a stepper motor project where I need to:

a) use one digital output pin from a microcontroller (Arduino Nano) to control to the step input to 8 different stepper motor drives (Moons' SR2-Plus). So basically, splitting the output pin 8 ways to the different drives so all drives are receiving the same control signal. This part seems simple enough, and I could use a voltage follower to avoid overloading the capacity of the output pin.

*and*

b) at times use the same digital output pin but only send a digital signal to a single particular motor drive.

I am stumped on how to be able to achieve both modes of operation here. Any general ideas or types of ICs out there that can help? I'd prefer to not use a bunch of mechanical switches if I can help it. The motor drives do have an enable/disable input, so I thought about taking advantage of those, but that completely frees the motor which is not ideal for this project.

Comment: Shift register, that is 3 pins (data, latch, clk). Though the clock and latch can be generated separately..serial-to-8-parallel SR are standard items e.g..the 595 logic piece

Comment: Thanks, @tobalt. I had not considered a shift register. After some thinking, I believe that I could use the parallel output from the 595 to represent which drives I am choosing and then "NAND gate" each of the eight 595 output pins with the same control signal. Thanks again! :)

Comment: motor drives that understand serial commands

Comment: An IC that might help is called an MCU. You can add more MCUs to handle subsystems, or get a big enough MCU to handle the whole system. You are not limited by Arduino, unless you want to be limited. What other limitations you have, price, size, power consumption?

Answer (score 0):

How about using two output pins and tie them together in the program when driving all the motors, and only drive the main output when driving one motor.

You can even use one output per motor, tie them all together when driving all of them. This way you can choose which motor to drive individually. But if it's always the same then 2 output pins will do.

O1 -> Motor that's also run individually.
O2 -> All the other motors in paraller.

In program (pseudo-code):
if (drivingAll) O2 = O1
else O2 = 0

If you can only use one output pin then how do you switch the mode between running all of them or only one?